# Determine whether the function is analytic or not (use Cauchy Riemann Equation)

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Given function $f(z)$ is written below :
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z-z^5}$$
I'm stuck at the beginning of the question itself. I don't know the approach to these type of questions. Please help!

Comment: Set $z=x+iy$ in your function and transform it under the following form $f(x,y)+i g(x,y)$ by using in particular multiplication by the complex conjugate of the denominator) then compute $\partial f/\partial y$ etc...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Analytic where? The domain has to be sepcified. It is certainly not analytic on the entire complex plane.

Comment: someone helped with the edit. can you guys please see the question again if possible